# enumeration literals

Tags: c#, enumeration

I want to know if there is some way I could declare an enumeration with integers. or if there is some other alternative i could use.

For example:

```
enum panelSizes { 300, 305, 310, 315, ..., 50000}
                  [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]       [940]
```

I need to assign some sort of ID to each size, so when the user inputs a specific width, I must be able to identify a respective cutSize witch is stored in a different Array.

This is my attempt to AVOID trying to read a excel file into my program and doing some sort of LOOKUP to identify certain related information.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: With linear values like that there is no need for a dictionary / enum to look things up unless Im missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

Since your approach doesn't allow names anyway, use an array:

```
 readonly int[] panelSizes = { 300, 305, 310, 315, ..., 50000};
```

and then, maybe, add an enum to index it:

```
 enum panelSizeNames { a300, a305, a310, a315, ... , a50000 }  // or better names
```

to get

```
 int size = panelSizes[panelSizeNames.a315];
```

Comment: I even wrote that down in my notes.. Sorry mate. That's perfect

Comment: If the `int` representation of an `enum` value is used as an array index, I think it's better to explicitly set the enumeration values: `enum panelSizeNames { a300 = 0, a305 = 1,... }`. Even if it's not actually required for now (`enum` are 0-based per default), it's better IMO, as it allows to change the index of a panelSizes value in the targeted array later easily.

Comment: The default numbering is perfect and eliminates one source of errors. The less manual work the better.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems like you would want to use an algorithm instead of a lookup to get the right cutsize. There is no need for a dictionary/enum/array if your values are linear like this.

```
    int panelSize = 5000;
    int index = (panelSize - 300)/5;
```

and the other way around

```
    int index = 940;
    int panelSize = (index * 5) + 300;
```

Comment: The thing is, I Actually have a spreadsheet with each panelsize's respective cut-size, number of holes depending on gap-size and whether or not the size is appropriate for installation. So i'll use the same reference (position) to get all that information

Comment: But your spreadsheet is linear? 300|0,305|1, 310|2 etc etc 5000|940 ? Right? Making the algo I provided return the same values as your spreadsheet would..

Answer (score 1):

How about a dictionary?

```
        Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>
        {
            { 0, 300 },
            { 1, 305 },
            { 2, 310 }
            ....
        };
```

Do note that if the key is an index from 0 to N, a simple array would be OK too...

Comment: I think the int[] would be a little less effort, since I'm comparing user input from a DataGrid, to the int[]'s values. Then the position will allow me to procure the respective value I need from a different array since they are at the same position. But thank you, I'm keen on learning all that I can. I'm very much new to C#

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary<int,int>` that you load up at the start with the id and width in it as the key and value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Using a struct, I was able to compare the input array to the array populated with the sizes  and then store each matching size's position in an array "Identities". Now I could easily write methods returning values from other arrays at the same positions... (resembling a spreadsheet lookUp)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PalisadeWorld
{   
//struct to store all the 'identities' of each panel size in an array
struct ID
    {
        public int[] Identities;
        public ID(int[] widths, int rows)
        {
            int[] allWidths = { 300, 305, 310, 315, 320, 325, 330, ..., 5000 };
            int i,j;
            int[] Ids = new int[rows];

            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 941; j++)
                {
                    if (widths[i] == allWidths[j])
                    {
                        Ids[i] = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Identities = Ids;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string data = String.Format("{0}", this.Identities);
            return data;
        }
    }

class LookUpSheet
{   
    //retrieve calculated widths and number of panels from NewOrder.cs
    public int[] lookUp_Widths {get; set;}
    public int lookUp_Rows { get; set; }

    //Method returning number of pales
    public int[] GetNumPales1()
    {
        int[] all_numPales = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ..."goes on till [941]"...};
        int[] numPales = new int[lookUp_Rows];

        ID select = new ID(lookUp_Widths, lookUp_Rows);

        for (int i = 0; i < lookUp_Rows; i++)
        {
            numPales[i] = all_numPales[select.Identities[i]];
        }

        return numPales;
    }
    //Method returning block sizes (mm)
    public int[] GetBlocks1()
    {
        int[] all_blocks = { 56, 59, 61, 64, 66, 69, 71, 74, "goes on till [941]"...};
        int[] blocks = new int[lookUp_Rows];

        ID select = new ID(lookUp_Widths, lookUp_Rows);

        for (int i = 0; i < lookUp_Rows; i++)
        {
            blocks[i] = all_blocks[select.Identities[i]];
        }
        return blocks;
    }
```

Thanks everyone!